# ng-show/ng-if confusion

Tags: angularjs

I have a

```
<button 
    class="tw-text-btn test-work-btn" 
    translate translate-attr-name="add_food"
    ng-click="add_food()" 
    ng-show="Permissions.allowed">
    <i class="icon-add-food"></i>
</button>
```

which works perfectly if `Permission.allowed` is true, button will show.

However, same thing does not work in this case:

```
<button 
    class="btn" 
    title="{{'remove_food'|translate}}" 
    ng-show="Permissions.allowed"
    ng-click="removefood($event, u)">
    <i class="icon-cancel"></i>
</button>
```

also side note, in second case if i have `food.$attributes.favfood_id !== myself` i should use `ng-if="food.$attributes.favfood_id !== myself && Permissions.allowed"`

but it still does not work even in that case, what am I missing..?

Comment: Please add more code. This much of code is not descriptive. Or try removing your class named btn. That might be suspect here. The class may contains some property which is making it hide.

Comment: For some reason, once i go to console and look at the line of code, this button gets ng-hide property. Any reason why? What else parts of code do you need?

Comment: Is the second button located in the same scope as the first button? Is `Permissions` on this scope?